# Django: show/log ORM sql calls from python shell

Tags: django, orm

Using the excellent [Django-Devserver](http://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver) I'm finding all kinds of interesting and unexpected SQL calls in my code. I wanted to find where the calls are coming from, and so I'm looking for a way to get a log or print-out of all SQL calls generated by the Django ORM in the Python shell. That is, when I do a Django ORM call via the Python shell, I'd like to see the resulting SQL printed out or logged.

I noticed several solutions that add log info to the html page. Is there an easy way to dump to the command line instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're in the shell, or anywhere for that matter, you can use the queryset method

```
query.as_sql()
```

to print the SQL command.

ie:

```
MyModel.objects.all().query.as_sql()
```

Comment: You can also do >>> print MyModel.objects.all().query

Comment: Using Django 1.5 and `query.as_sql()` does not work for me. `query.sql_with_params()` does however.

Answer (score 205):

If you're using Django 1.3:

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Comment: What if I'm using django 1.2?

Comment: @jrwren, at least for development

Comment: amazing! by adding this snippet to my startup.py file I can effectively print SQL debug info everytime I debug my code into the django shell

Comment: +1 this works with django 1.5 as well, also where have you been all my life?

Comment: This is still useful with Django 1.8.

Comment: The ruby on rails console has this kind of output enabled by default and I was looking to replicate that; excellent!

Comment: Should I put this code in settings.py? Noob here. please help.

Comment: how to display the output?

Comment: Still works on Django 4.4

Answer (score 50):

I was trying to use "[Django: show/log ORM sql calls from python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314920/django-show-log-orm-sql-calls-from-python-shell/5835465#5835465)" in a shell on a production server, and it wasn't working. Eventually someone pointed out that it will only do this debug logging when `DEBUG = True`. But you can work around that like this:

```
import logging
from django.db import connection
connection.force_debug_cursor = True  # Change to use_debug_cursor in django < 1.8
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

I'm leaving this here so I can find it later, and hopefully it saves someone else the same digging I did.

Comment: you bro, are a good man, saved my day and my prod database

Answer (score 39):

Use django extensions.

```
pip install django-extensions
./manage.py shell_plus --print-sql
```

For production environments it might not work due to debug settings.

Comment: Even in production, you can run `settings.DEBUG=True` as first Python shell_plus command.

Comment: If the query Django generates is too long (which is likely unless your tables have only a few columns), the shell simply stops printing and moves on to the execution time. None of the queries I'm seeing even get to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 32):

Rob Hudson's [Django Debug Toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar), as well as its general awesomness, also includes a pretty nifty `debugsqlshell` manage.py command which does exactly this.

Comment: To find where calls are coming from and whats going on "behind the scenes" I would also recommend Django Debug Toolbar. Not only for the debugsqlshell command but also for the actual toolbar which also has a lot of information on SQL calls.

Answer (score 8):

```
qs = YourModel.objects.all()

qs.query.get_compiler('default').as_sql()
```

Comment: str(qs) does the job as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you're really serious about wanting to see/log all SQL queries, you'll want to try Django 1.3 (currently in alpha, but soon to be production) which enables [Python loggers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) for many components, including the database backends.

Of course, if you're stuck using a stable version of Django, you can get the same effect relatively easily by patching `django/db/models/sql/compiler.py` by adding this to the bottom of the import list:

```
import logging
_querylogger = logging.getLogger( 'sql.compiler' )
```

The find the `SQLCompiler::execute_sql()` method and change:

```
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute( sql, params )
```

to this:

```
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    _querylogger.info( "%s <= %s", sql, params )
    cursor.execute( sql, params )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention another option - I've made the `django-sql-sniffer` tool so that it can attach to any running Python process and monitor/analyze SQL execution coming from Django ORM.

As such it can also be used to monitor queries coming from a Python shell process (see [github](https://github.com/gruuya/django-sql-sniffer) page for the demo video):

- open shell and get process ID:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.getpid()
Out[2]: 99688
```

- attach `django-sql-sniffer` in another tab (and in this case specify the tail mode to follow the queries live)

```
$ django-sql-sniffer -p 99688 -t
```

- go back to your shell and start executing queries

```
In [3]: cat library/models.py
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


In [4]: from library.models import *

In [5]: books = Book.objects.all()

In [6]: len(books)  # better use count
Out[6]: 121000

In [7]: book = books.first()  # query set not ordered, will hit db again

In [8]: book = books.first()  # query set not ordered, will hit db again

In [9]: book = books.first()  # query set not ordered, will hit db again

In [10]: book.author.id  # better use author_id
Out[10]: 1

In [11]: Book.objects.filter(author__first_name__startswith='A').count() > 0
Out[11]: True

In [12]: Book.objects.filter(author__first_name__startswith='A').exists()
Out[12]: True
```

- the tool prints the raw queries as they get executed

```
Count: 1; Duration: 0.002211809; Max Duration: 0.002211809; Query:
SELECT "library_book"."id",
       "library_book"."title",
       "library_book"."author_id"
  FROM "library_book"
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1; Duration: 0.000240326; Max Duration: 0.000240326; Query:
SELECT "library_book"."id",
       "library_book"."title",
       "library_book"."author_id"
  FROM "library_book"
 ORDER BY "library_book"."id" ASC
 LIMIT 1
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 2; Duration: 0.000150919; Max Duration: 0.000240326; Query:
SELECT "library_book"."id",
       "library_book"."title",
       "library_book"."author_id"
  FROM "library_book"
 ORDER BY "library_book"."id" ASC
 LIMIT 1
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 3; Duration: 0.000187874; Max Duration: 0.000240326; Query:
SELECT "library_book"."id",
       "library_book"."title",
       "library_book"."author_id"
  FROM "library_book"
 ORDER BY "library_book"."id" ASC
 LIMIT 1
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1; Duration: 0.000919104; Max Duration: 0.000919104; Query:
SELECT "library_author"."id",
       "library_author"."first_name",
       "library_author"."last_name"
  FROM "library_author"
 WHERE "library_author"."id" = %s
 LIMIT 21
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1; Duration: 0.040677071; Max Duration: 0.040677071; Query:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
  FROM "library_book"
 INNER JOIN "library_author"
    ON ("library_book"."author_id" = "library_author"."id")
 WHERE "library_author"."first_name" LIKE %s ESCAPE '\'
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1; Duration: 0.002345800; Max Duration: 0.002345800; Query:
SELECT (1) AS "a"
  FROM "library_book"
 INNER JOIN "library_author"
    ON ("library_book"."author_id" = "library_author"."id")
 WHERE "library_author"."first_name" LIKE %s ESCAPE '\'
 LIMIT 1
-------------------------------------------------------
```

- finally, hit `Ctrl + C` to stop the tool and get an analysis of all captured queries

```
=======================================================

  ____    ___   _       ____  _____   _   _____  ____
 / ___|  / _ \ | |     / ___||_   _| / \ |_   _|/ ___|
 \___ \ | | | || |     \___ \  | |  / _ \  | |  \___ \
  ___) || |_| || |___   ___) | | | / ___ \ | |   ___) |
 |____/  \__\_\|_____| |____/  |_|/_/   \_\|_|  |____/

               Django SQL Sniffer v1.0.0
=======================================================
             TOP QUERIES BY MAX DURATION


Count: 1; Max Duration: 0.040677071; Combined Duration: 0.040677071; Query:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
  FROM "library_book"
 INNER JOIN "library_author"
    ON ("library_book"."author_id" = "library_author"."id")
 WHERE "library_author"."first_name" LIKE %s ESCAPE '\'
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1; Max Duration: 0.002345800; Combined Duration: 0.002345800; Query:
SELECT (1) AS "a"
  FROM "library_book"
 INNER JOIN "library_author"
    ON ("library_book"."author_id" = "library_author"."id")
 WHERE "library_author"."first_name" LIKE %s ESCAPE '\'
 LIMIT 1
-------------------------------------------------------
Count: 1; Max Duration: 0.002211809; Combined Duration: 0.002211809; Query:
SELECT "library_book"."id",
       "library_book"."title",
       "library_book"."author_id"
  FROM "library_book"
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
```