# Django how do i view query in manage shell

Tags: django

How can i see my django queries from manage shell interface

I have tried using this but gives me queries that pass through the django server

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries()
```

I have seen it somewhere, can't remember where??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: show/log ORM sql calls from python shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314920/django-show-log-orm-sql-calls-from-python-shell)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Django how do i view query in manage shell

There are two ways to view the query in the ***shell***. First, if you are using a queryset you can use the `query` attribute of the queryset. For e.g.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
print(qs.query)
```

Second when the query is not visible immediately. For e.g. when you are updating a queryset using `update()`. In this case you can:

```
from django.db import connection
MyModel.objects.all().update(foo = 'bar')
print(connection.queries)
# print(connection.queries[-1]) # if you want to see only the last query
```

> I have tried using this but gives me queries that pass through the django server

I don't understand what you mean by "gives me queries that pass through the Django server". Are you trying to see the queries while running the application? In that case use the [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) or the [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/93/) referred to by [@rubayeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878913/django-how-do-i-view-query-in-manage-shell/3878960#3878960).

Comment: Ok, what i was doing was assigning the queryset to a variable e.g cur = Entry.objects.all(). But am ok now. thanks

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use [django extensions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extensions). You can install it with

```
$ pip install django-extensions
```

Start your shell with

```
./manage.py shell_plus --print-sql
```

Run a query

```
In [1]: Book.objects.all()
Out[1]: SELECT "book_book"."id", "book_book"."name", "book_book"."author_id" FROM "book_book" LIMIT 21

Execution time: 0.087548s [Database: default]

<QuerySet [<Book: The Stranger>, <Book: Atlas Shrugged>]>
```

If you don't want to append `--print-sql` every time, in your django settings, you can set

```
SHELL_PLUS_PRINT_SQL = True
```

An alternate way is to enable logging for db queries.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        }
    },
}
```

Add this to your settings and restart your shell to see SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can print out the sql for individual queries like so:

```
your_query = YourModel.objects.all()
print your_query.query
```

Is that all you need?

Answer (score 0):

I use [this Django code snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/93/) that lists all the queries in a view in the rendered template. Pretty useful.