# django database query optimisation

Tags: django, django-orm, database-optimization

a newbie question on django db query optimisation:

I have a custom model form to edit a Destination object, and I in the constructor I get hold of a queryset from a related Visitor model, which has ManyToMany field into Destination(see EDIT for the reason to use a custom model form)

```
    print "loading initial choices"
    visitor_choices, visitor_initial = [], []
    visitor_set = self.instance.visitor_set.all()
    print visitor_set
    for obj in Visitor.objects.all():
        visitor_choices.append((obj.pk, obj.name))
        #if visitor_set.filter(pk=obj.pk # this hits the db every time!
        if obj in visitor_set:
            visitor_initial.append(obj.pk)

    self.fields['visitors'].choices = visitor_choices
    self.fields['visitors'].initial = visitor_initial

    print "finished loading initial choices"
```

The idea was to load the related visitor_set into a variable, to avoid repeated queries to check if each visitor is present in the visitor_set. Is this the best approach?

Also, if I switch on db logging (as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314920/django-show-log-orm-sql-calls-from-python-shell), second answer), I can see a repeated query (the 3rd SELECT statement) to select all visitors for destination id 1, but this is nowhere in the code I wrote, where does it come from?

```
loading initial choices
(0.000) SELECT "testapp_visitor"."id", "testapp_visitor"."name" FROM "testapp_visitor" INNER JOIN "testapp_visitor_destinations" ON ("testapp_visitor"."id" = "testapp_visitor_destinations"."visitor_id") WHERE "testapp_visitor_destinations"."destination_id" = 1  LIMIT 21; args=(1,
)
[<Visitor: MIMA>, <Visitor: MIMO>, <Visitor: MIMU>]
(0.000) SELECT "testapp_visitor"."id", "testapp_visitor"."name" FROM "testapp_visitor"; args=()
(0.000) SELECT "testapp_visitor"."id", "testapp_visitor"."name" FROM "testapp_visitor" INNER JOIN "testapp_visitor_destinations" ON ("testapp_visitor"."id" = "testapp_visitor_destinations"."visitor_id") WHERE "testapp_visitor_destinations"."destination_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
finished loading initial choices
```

**EDIT**

The `Destination` object I refer to is the related side of a `ManyToMany` field on a `Visitor` object. If my form was editing the Visitor object itself then Django would handle the `ManyToMany` field automatically. But to do that on the model form for `Destination` I need to add a multiple choice field for `Visitor` and customize the `__init__` method to load the choices and initial selections for it.

The question however is about how to handle the queryset, and the mysterious 2nd sql to load the manytomany values, which I can also see from the shell:

```
>>> from testapp.forms import DestinationForm
>>> from testapp.models import Destination, Visitor
>>> dest = Destination.objects.get(pk=1)
(0.001) SELECT "testapp_destination"."id", "testapp_destination"."destination" FROM "testapp_destination" WHERE "testapp_destination"."id" =
 1 ; args=(1,)
>>> destinationForm = DestinationForm(instance=dest)
loading initial choices
(0.000) SELECT "testapp_visitor"."id", "testapp_visitor"."name" FROM "testapp_visitor" INNER JOIN "testapp_visitor_destinations" ON ("testap
p_visitor"."id" = "testapp_visitor_destinations"."visitor_id") WHERE "testapp_visitor_destinations"."destination_id" = 1  LIMIT 21; args=(1,
)
[<Visitor: MIMA>, <Visitor: MIMO>, <Visitor: MIMU>]
(0.000) SELECT "testapp_visitor"."id", "testapp_visitor"."name" FROM "testapp_visitor"; args=()
(0.000) SELECT "testapp_visitor"."id", "testapp_visitor"."name" FROM "testapp_visitor" INNER JOIN "testapp_visitor_destinations" ON ("testap
p_visitor"."id" = "testapp_visitor_destinations"."visitor_id") WHERE "testapp_visitor_destinations"."destination_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
finished loading initial choices
>>>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you are trying to achieve? To me it looks like you're doing what django should do by default if you generate a `ModelForm` for a model in which `visitor` is a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: yes, you are right, my form tries to save a 'Destination' model which is at the related end of a ManytoMany fields on my 'Visitor' model, i'll post the models to clarify. So i could have a form to save 'Visitor' instead, which would handle automatically the ManyToMany, however i wanted to explore this way of doing it. My question however is about the way I handle the querysets, and the strange additional sql statement I see in the logging

Answer (score 1):

To answer what you say is your question: I think the query

```
SELECT "testapp_visitor"."id", "testapp_visitor"."name" FROM "testapp_visitor" INNER JOIN "testapp_visitor_destinations" ON ("testapp_visitor"."id" = "testapp_visitor_destinations"."visitor_id") WHERE "testapp_visitor_destinations"."destination_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
```

comes from the line

```
if obj in visitor_set:
```

where Django re-executes the query of `visitor_set` (see [When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) in the Django docs). You can avoid that by converting `visitor_set` to a `set` right away (so Django is forced to execute the query immediately), as in:

```
visitor_set = set(self.instance.visitor_set.all())
```

This will also improve the performance of testing whether an object is in this set (in comparison to a `list` or similar iterable).