# Access to fields of prefetch_related on reverse relation

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have this models

```
class Animal(models.model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Dog(Animal):
    field = models.IntegerField()

class Owner(models.model):
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal)
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now suppose that I want all Dogs and their owner's names.

```
dogs = Dog.objects.all().prefetch_related('owner_set')
```

How do I access `owner.name` from `dogs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it from `owner_set`:

```
[owner.name for dog in dogs for owner in dog.owner_set.all()]
```

Unlike `select_related()`, `prefetch_related()` precaches data from related objects, so this won't hit the database each time we need an owner_set per dog - see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related).

Comment: This will hit the database again. I found `dogs._prefetched_objects_cache` but i don't now how i use it.

Comment: @balsagoth according to docs, it shouldn't. See updated answer and an example in docs.

Comment: @balsagoth actually I've tested it, it doesn't make any additional database queries while calling `dog.owner_set.all()`. You can test it in django shell, for example, turn on database logging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5835465/771848.

Comment: Ok, i found what i was missing. I have a `related_name` on that field. And if you have a related_name, you have to look with that related_name. Not with `owner_set`. Thank you

Comment: @balsagoth that's just how you call it instead of `owner_set`. The idea stays pretty much the same.