# Django: copying file copies only a part

Tags: python, django

I have the following method to copy all files in a `directory_path` to [my django model](https://github.com/omeinusch/Palco/blob/master/engine/filestorage/models.py).  Well, this works as expected: copy the files to the place as definied in the model with `upload_to`. But there's a problem: not everything is copied. Only a part of the files. Like 17.530 bytes and not the ~1-2 megabytes. :( This makes me very sad.

```
def _handle_directory(self, directory_path, directory):
    for fs_name in os.listdir(directory_path):
        fs_path = os.path.join(directory_path, fs_name)
        if os.path.isfile(fs_path):
            path = os.path.join(directory_path, fs_path)
            with open(path, 'r') as f:
                file_wrapper = File(f)
                self.cnt_files += 1
                new_file = FsFile(directory=directory,
                                  filename=fs_name.decode(self.fs_encoding).encode('utf-8'),
                                  file=file_wrapper, uploader=self.uploader)
                new_file.save()
```

**Update 1:**

I ran this with three files:

```
filename   | orig. size | imported size |  ratio
 foo.pdf   |  70.818    |  1365         |   1,92 %
 bar.html  |   3.355    |  3355         | 100 %
 fiz.zip   |     645    |  135          |  20,93 %
```

Comment: I can't spot an obvious problem. Gather more data. Try with another file. Same problem? The **exact same** amount of bytes copied no matter the file size? A similar percentage? No? If you try with an in-memory string (use `StringIO` to make it look like a file), same results? Are you swallowing exceptions somewhere up the call chain? Try with a local try-catch inside the function

Comment: i updated my question with the file sizes. there was no exception.

Comment: Does the same file get the same % every time you try? Could it be, perhaps, that you're using an asynchronous thread or process to copy the file, and you're not waiting for the copying to complete before closing the file?

Comment: Likely unrelated, but: Why do you use 'r' instead of 'rb' for filemode with binary files; and do you os.path.join the directory_path twice on purpose?

Comment: well, jensq, this was the solution: `b`-flag was missing :D If you post this as an answer, I mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I answer this question, because jensq did not.

I had to add the `b`-flag to `open`:

```
        with open(path, 'rb') as f:
```

Then everything works the way I expected.