# Get update query when DEBUG is False, without affecting code execution

Tags: django, django-orm

I would like to view the queries run inside a block of code, ideally getting it as a list of strings.

Of course there are [similar SO questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running), but they do not address my three specific requirements:

- Works for queries other than `SELECT`.
- Works when the code is not in `DEBUG` mode.
- The code executes normally, i.e. any production code runs as production code.

What I have so far is a transaction inside a `DEBUG=True` override, that is instantly rolled back after the queries are collected.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connections
from django.db import transaction
from django.test.utils import override_settings

@contextmanager
@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
def print_query():
    class OhNo(Exception):
        pass
    queries = []
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            yield
            for connection in connections:
                queries.extend(connections[connection].queries)
            print(queries)
            raise OhNo
    except OhNo:
        pass

def do_special_debug_thing():
    print('haha yes')

with print_query():
    Foo.objects.update(bar=1)
    if settings.DEBUG:
        do_special_debug_thing()
```

There are two problems with that snippet:

- That `DEBUG` override doesn't do anything. The context manager prints out `[]`.
- If the `DEBUG` override is effective, then `do_special_debug_thing` is called, which I do not want to happen.

So, as far as I know, there is no way to collect all queries made inside a block of code, including those that are `SELECT` statements, while `DEBUG` is off. What ways are there to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at this answer for collection all queries when debug is not on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394237/6682340

Comment: @Krukas that's not really getting queries back as a list of strings, but better than having nothing definitely, will give it a go, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do that only once, getting queries separately and put them in a list could help you.

```
update = Foo.objects.filter(bar=1)
query = str(update.query)
print(query)
```

Comment: Well, the return of an `.update()` is the integer value of the number of rows updated, and the return of a `.delete()` is a dict. This is not a viable option. (Edit: it's an incorrect answer altogether, but I'll skip the downvoting because you tried to help.)

Comment: @Brian you are right. I was talking about logging the querysets. I just copied and paste your code and forgot to change to `filter()`. I'll fix.

Comment: If you do that, your answer no longer satisfies the "Works for queries other than `SELECT`" part of the question.